# How to use perform division between two sums

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I try to do something the following division using sum over two columns like this.

```
Report.sum('(clicks_count / nullif(sum(views_count),0))')
```

But I get the error `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested`.

I'm a bit stuck in how to perform this query in ActiveRecord, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Report.sum(clicks_count) / Report.sum(view_count)`.

If you'd like to use only one query, then you can use `pluck`:

```
Report.pluck('sum(clicks_count) / nullif(sum(views_count),0))').first
```

You can also group by another attribute (for example `date`):

```
Report.group(:date).pluck('sum(clicks_count) / nullif(sum(views_count),0))')
```

This will give you the clicks_count sum divided by views_count sum for each `date`.

Comment: Thanks. That seem to be fine if the idea is to query only one result but how could I group all results by date (day)?

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution to group by `date`.